# Querying a Data Table Using Select Method in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

I have data in a `DataTable` object and I want to retrieve specific data from a data table on some certain conditions, for to query a data table using its select method

My database is MySQL 8.0.17 version

I tried this code without success because the error on VS 2019 is

> The [ABW] column could not be found string

But the `[ABW]` don't is the name of column but value of column `CountryCode`

What's wrong with this code?

Please, any help?

```
DataTable cgv = new DataTable();
DataTable dtCustomers;
DataTable dtOrders;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        // Create a datatable as a DataSource of GridViews
        dtCustomers = new DataTable(); // parent gridview datasource
        dtOrders = new DataTable(); // child gridview datasource

        dtOrders = GetData("SELECT CountryCode, Language, IsOfficial, Percentage FROM `tCustomers`");
        cgv = dtOrders; // set child datatable to temporary datatable

        dtCustomers = GetData("SELECT CountryCode, Language, IsOfficial, Percentage FROM `tCustomers`;");
        gvCustomers.DataSource = dtCustomers;
        gvCustomers.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void gvCustomers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string CountryCode = gvCustomers.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        GridView gvOrders = ((GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvOrders"));

        dtOrders.Columns[0].ColumnName = "CountryCode";

        DataRow[] dr = dtOrders.Select(dtOrders.Columns[0].ColumnName + "=" + CountryCode.ToString());

        gvOrders.DataSource = dr; // set child datatable to parent gridview as datasource
        gvOrders.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
protected void gvParent_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string CountryCode = gvCustomers.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        GridView gvOrders = ((GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvOrders"));

        cgv.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CountryCode='" + CountryCode.ToString() + "'";
        gvOrders.DataSource = cgv;
        gvOrders.DataBind();
    }
}
```